# Generate jpql queries dynamically based on values provided/not provided from multiple choice lists

Tags: jpa, jpql

I have four choice lists on my HTML page and I'm retrieving data when the choices are selected. How do I dynamically create a jqpl query based on the selection on the choice lists.

In my case, there are 4 choice lists and a user can either select options from all the lists or a combination of them. How do I write my query in this scenario?

My query is something like

```
SELECT x FROM tablename x WHERE x.column1= :choice1 AND x.column2 = :choice2 AND x.column3 = :choice3 AND x.column4 = :choice4
```

Comment: Can you please include the code for what you have tried already.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you may try this [Criteria API](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjivm.html)

Answer (score 0):

Very simple. You can use a `Map` to save the paremeters in each condition that verify if the choiceX exists.

Example:

```
String jpql = "SELECT x FROM tablename x WHERE 1 = 1 ";

Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();

if (choice1 != null) {
    jpql += "x.column1 = :choice1 ";
    parameters.put("choice1", choice1);
}

if (choice2 != null) {
    jpql += "x.column2 = :choice2 ";
    parameters.put("choice2", choice2);
}

Query query = entityManager.createQuery(jpql);

for (Entry<String, Object> entry : parameters.entrySet()) {
    query.setParameter(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}

return query.getResultList();
```